# Scraping Multiple Data Tables at once in Python

Tags: python, html, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using the following NCAA stats site and want to scrape data from it:

https://stats.ncaa.org/rankings/change_sport_year_div

*To get to the specific data I want to scrape, click the link, choose the sport Men's Basketball, year 2019-2020, and Division III, then click the team stats button.* After digging through the html, I was able to find all of the stats from the drop down menu that I want. I was wondering if there was potentially a way to use BeautifulSoup (or perhaps even pd.read_html()) to scrape a table for each category. It appears as though all the info I may need is in the picture below, but I'm not quite sure how to implement python's tools to capitalize. This would be way more efficient (and a lot less boring) to do than manually downloading the excel sheet for each stat and reading them into pandas. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Inspecting your case, you should make a post request to the given url with some form data as follows:

```
sport_code: MBB
academic_year: 2020.0
division: 3.0
ranking_period: 110.0
team_individual: T
game_high: N
ranking_summary: N
```

---

```
sport_code=MBB&academic_year=2020.0&division=3.0&ranking_period=110.0&team_individual=T&game_high=N&ranking_summary=N
```

Format the form data as shown above and call curl,

```
curl -X POST -d "@formdata.txt" https://stats.ncaa.org/rankings/change_sport_year_div
```

---

If you please you could also do the same thing with `requests` module, just make sure form data is in correct format.

```
r = requests.post("https://stats.ncaa.org/rankings/change_sport_year_div",
                  data={"sport_code": "MBB",
                        "academic_year": 2020.0,
                        "division": 3.0,
                        "ranking_period": 110.0,
                        "team_individual": "T",
                        "game_high": "N",
                        "ranking_summary": "N"})
```

Comment: How did you find a token and those parameters? I can't seem to find an API/API documentation for this site.

Comment: There is no API in these kind of websites, open chrome devtools and look at the network tab. Click the `type:document`, there is `Form Data` under `Headers`.

Comment: I'm kind of confused on how to format the code in your original response. What do I do with all of those variables? I was able to find them on my machine and have my own token. It is listed as a dictionary. I have imported requests already.

Comment: Also, the dictionary won't run because the key 'stat_seq' doesn't have a value pair.

Comment: When I run the following code I get an error 
r = requests.post('<https://stats.ncaa.org/rankings/change_sport_year_div>', data = {'sport_code': 'MBB',
'academic_year': 2020.0,
'division': 3.0,
'ranking_period': 110.0,
'team_individual': 'T',
'game_high': 'N',
'ranking_summary': 'N',
'org_id': -1,
'stat_seq': '',
'conf_id': -1,
'region_id': -1,
'ncaa_custom_rank_summary_id': -1,
'user_custom_rank_summary_id': -1,
'authenticity_token': '1qX+xH/PoudepD8bA4ZV+3sObi98u2rI59KoqHH1B00='})
InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found

Comment: My apologies. I really appreciate your help. I ran the following code:

tables = pd.read_html(r.text)

and it returned a list of 15 tables. These are the tables listed on the webpage and only return the top 5 teams, as shown on the webpage. I would like all 32 statistical categories for all teams. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: There is a changing form data when you select different categories from the dropdown which is `"stat_seq": 474`. I don't know what this corresponds to but you should make your way from here. I don't have more time to do your job instead of you, give it some effort please.